# PowerShell index value of PSObject

Tags: powershell

So the below Object and Foreach loop does exactly what I need it to do, and that is find out if even or odd per line.

```
$anon = @()
$anon += [PSCustomObject] @{ Name = "i am a thing" ; Location = "1" ; Value = $false }
$anon += [PSCustomObject] @{ Name = "I also do stuff" ; Location = "2" ; Value = $false }
$anon += [PSCustomObject] @{ Name = "I have been known to do stuff" ; Location = "3" ; Value = $true }
$anon += [PSCustomObject] @{ Name = "I do nothing" ; Location = "4" ; Value = $true }

Foreach ( $anonauth in $anon ) {
    If ( $anonauth.location % 2 -eq 0 ) { 
        "I am even, and will do X"   
    }
    Else {
        "I am odd, and will do y"
    }
}
```

What I'm curious to know is, is there a way of performing the same task without "location" as a reference point for the IF even/odd?

There are four lines in my Object, is there a way of using the [0],[1],[2],[3] as the calculation reference?

Does that make sense? Just seems a waste to have a reference number when I'm pretty sure it already exists?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an "old school" [for-loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-6):

```
$anon = @()
$anon += [PSCustomObject] @{ Name = "i am a thing" ; Value = $false }
$anon += [PSCustomObject] @{ Name = "I also do stuff" ; Value = $false }
$anon += [PSCustomObject] @{ Name = "I have been known to do stuff" ; Value = $true }
$anon += [PSCustomObject] @{ Name = "I do nothing"; Value = $true }

for( $i =0; $i -lt $anon.Count; $i++ ) {
    If ( $i % 2 -eq 0 ) { 
        "I am even, and will do X"   
    }
    Else {
        "I am odd, and will do y"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @GrahamJordan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might implement some `$counter` variable in your foreach loop, keeping track of the number of items you have iterated over thus far:

```
$counter = 0
Foreach ( $anonauth in $anon ) {
    $counter += 1 # or, use $counter++
    If ( $counter % 2 -eq 0 ) { 
        "I am even, and will do X"   
    }
    Else {
        "I am odd, and will do y"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way myself and a work colleague discussed would work too, it still feels like throwing an extra variable in there when I'm sure we already have one. Though I could be wrong, maybe it's not a thing the moment you dip inside the Object(?)

In any case, thank you.

Comment: There is no such way that I'm aware of - otherwise, it would be adding some (albeit small) extra overhead for every `ForEach` loop used when one of the niceties of using `ForEach` instead of `For` is that you can stay away from the arithmetic and focus on the actual values of the array.

Comment: That makes sense. It can't be done without bringing another variable into question. Thank you!